# Fastest way to store tiny data on the server

Tags: c, performance, apache, storage

I'm looking for a better and faster way to store data on my webserver at the best speed possible.

My idea is to log the IP address of every incoming request to any website on the server and if it reaches a certain number within a set time then users will be redirected to a page where they need to enter a code to regain access.

I created an apache module that does just that. It attempts to create files on a ramdisk however I constantly run into permission problems since there is another module that switches users before my module has a chance to run.

Using a physical disk is an option that is too slow.

So my only options are as follows:

1. Either create folders on the ramdrive for each website so IP addresses can be logged independently.
2. Somehow figure out how to make my apache module execute its functionality before all other modules.

OR

3. Allocate a huge amount of ram and store everything in it.

If I choose option #2, then I'll continue to beat around the bush as I have already attempted that.

If I choose option #1, then I might need lots more ram as tons of duplicate IP addresses are expected to be stored across several folders on the ramdrive.

If I choose option #3, then the apache module will have to constantly seek through the ram space allocated in order to find the IP address, and seeking takes time.

People say that memory access is faster than file access but I'm not sure if just a direct memory access via malloc is faster than storing data to a ram drive.

The reason why I expect to collect alot of IP addresses is to block script-kiddies from constantly accessing my server at a very high rate.

So what I'm asking is what is the best way I should store my data and why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "seeking" through RAM. "RAM" stands for "*Random* Access Memory". Any access to it is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Could you use a heap-based heuristic approach, with 4 `unsigned array[256]` to count requests made by each part of the IP? Then focus on the highest from each array.

Comment: Guess what a RAM drive does when you write to it. It stores the data in RAM... after that data has gone through several processing steps that aren't instant. It's certainly not *faster* than just storing the data in RAM to start with.

Comment: @WeatherVane If I understand your idea, I think you mean making a 4-dimensional array where each dimension is one part of an ip address. It's great as an answer, but the memory requirements are very high. declaring even a `char[255][255][255][255]` would take slightly over 4GB ram which is half my entire server space but I only have maybe 1 or 2GB to work with as the rest of the memory is used to serve websites through apache.

Comment: @Mike no I didn't mean making one 4-D array, but four 1-D arrays.

Comment: How would 4 1-D arrays process the data for individual IP addresses quickly?

Comment: Maybe use Redis, which is very fast and efficient, and use a `Time-To-Live`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hashmap` instead of huge amount of ram. It will be pretty fast.

May be several hashmaps for each websits. Or use composite like `string_hash(website_name) + (int_hash(ip) << 32)`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with permissions, why not solve it at that level? Use a common user account or group. Or make everything on the RAM disk world readable/writable.

If you want to solve it at the Apache level, you might want to look into [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) and [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442).

Comment: I thought of that but at the same time, that introduces a security risk because more than one user has access to the server and if the data is world writable and one day, an authorized user gives an unauthorized user access to the system whether intentionally or not, then that malicious user could corrupt the data if he/she figures it all out and at the rate that script kiddies ruin servers, these hackers could almost figure anything out